# Multiple instances of kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I understand that multiple instances of a producer application can be started to produce data to a topic. What configuration changes are required for this? Do i need different client_id? Without any changes , it works. So not sure if there are any benefit of changing client id or any other config param?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client id is simply used for logging on the server.

> The purpose of this is to be able to track the source of requests beyond just ip/port by allowing a logical application name to be included in server-side request logging.

So it's not very important unless you have many producers in the same application.

To get a different client id for each producer, you would need a producer factory for each.

On the consumer side, you can specify a client id at the container (or `@KafkaListener`) level.